# jasmine-karma handleGlobalErrors

Tags: jasmine, karma-jasmine, karma-runner

I'm using the Karma-Jasmine framework plugin and have some flaky tests that sometimes throw an exception in a beforeAll method within a suite.   Unfortunately this appears to prevent all subsequent test suites from running and in particular the reporter plugins don't report any details that tests were skipped and they just disappear from reporter output.

This Karma-Jasmine runner has a function called handleGlobalErrors that reports if there was any failed expectations back to Karma and this error message appears to causes Karma to stop running tests.

Anyone have ideas/thoughts on possibility of logging the error as an 'info' message and continue to attempt to run tests?  or am I missing some kind of Karma configuration option?